# Mac OS xargs adds '?[m' at the end of line

Tags: grep, osx, git, xargs

I am trying to delete some local git branches with

```
git branch -D $(git branch | grep 'RTL-1[1|2|3]' | xargs)
```

However I am getting this kind of error

```
error: branch 'RTL-1114_branch_name1?[m' not found.
error: branch 'RTL-1224_branch_name2?[m' not found.
error: branch 'RTL-1225_another_branch?[m' not found.
```

For some reason string "?[m" is being added, but without git command I am getting casual print of branches separates by space.
I believe it worked on my linux machine, is it different on MacOS?

Comment: Apart from everything else, `[1|2|3]` would match the characters `1`, `2`, `3` and `|`. You probably meant `[123]`. And `xargs` by itself will just echo its arguments, so that part of the pipeline could be removed completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve probably got `git` and/or `grep` configured to always output using colours; in that case,

```
git branch -D $(git branch --color=never | grep --color=never 'RTL-1[123]')
```

should work.

You can use `git`’s own pattern-matching:

```
git branch -D $(git branch --color=never -l '*RTL-1[123]*')
```

To avoid this in future, you should use the `auto` setting for `color`: it will output colour when outputting to a terminal, and won’t otherwise. To configure `git` appropriately:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

For `grep`, check your aliases.

Comment: Could also be greps color via an alias, but this is why color=auto flags exist (and should be used).

Comment: Good point @D.BenKnoble, I’ve added that to my answer. If it was `grep` though I’d expect a colour escape at the start of the match too.